# Python download request fails when file name has a plus (+) sign

Tags: python, python-requests, urlencode

I'm writing an application in Python to download files from a server (actually a NAS) of a friend of mine that we use for file sharing. I use its official API combined with the requests module.

Application has a bug that when the file requested has a plus (+) sign in the name the request response is "Bad gateway" (502) instead of OK (200) and download fails because it can't find the file.

If I remove the plus sign from the file name, it works.

If the name has any other special characters like underscores, dots, parenthesis, brackets, etc. it works.

Error only happens when a plus sign.

I know it has something to do with url encode skipping the plus sign for some reason and not converting it into a "%2B" which I think would be the expected behaviour if I'm not wrong.

I've seen here many questions talking about the urllib module but not sure if that's what I need and how I would use it to encode the. After many days of heavy researching I can't figure out how to fix this.

The line of code that sets the download request URL is:

```
download_request = requests.get(url+DOWNLOAD_API.format(path, file, sid), stream=True)
```

DOWNLOAD_API is:

```
DOWNLOAD_API = 'webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.Download&version=2&method=download&path=/{}/{}&mode=open&_sid={}'
```

Example of final URL causing the error:

```
'https://mynas.quickconnect.to:65375/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.Download&version=2&method=download&path=/video/Example%20file+.txt&mode=open&_sid=qoHtK6Lu2TChqMJzMov65_yOg3c4e9hXKG8BTq-z3zUrbOQd2AFoEJNhSuN3uFfWFAQNh-Hf53E3nZ1v6ggX7A'
```

*I've been looking for how to ask a good question in Stackoverflow because I'm not very used to it. Hopefully I did well.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `+` in URL encoding represents a space. It has to be encoded as `%2B` to be a real `+`. You should try that! Or use a dict and the [`params`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) argument.

Comment: "urlencode skipping the plus sign for some reason" - does that mean it also does not encode it when you call urlencode yourself? And does it work if you write the `%2B` instead?

Comment: Where do you do any `urlencoding`? Anyway - you shouldn't have to as `requests` will do that for you... eg: `requests.get('https:/somemwhere.com/webapi/entry.cgi', params={'api': 'whatever', 'version': 2, 'method': 'download', 'path': '/x/y/z'})` etc... so make sure the first bit of the full url to entry.cgi and change the rest of the parameters so they're what's needed and it should work.

Comment: Sorry, I was meant the requests module itself wasn't encoding the url properly skipping the plus sign. I didn't do any url encoding manually as I expected the requests module to do it itself as it does with other special characters like I mentioned in the question. @JonClements I'm gonna try that! Thank you very much guys.

Answer (score 0):

@JonClements answer was correct.

If you format the URL like I was doing:

```
download_request = requests.get(url+DOWNLOAD_API.format(path, file, sid), stream=True)
```

then you have to manually encode plus signs as %2B. Instead, you want to set all the parameters within the requests.get method, like this:

```
download_request = requests.get(url, 
                                params={'api':'SYNO.FileStation.Download', 'version': 2, 'method':'download', 'path':"/"+path+"/"+file, 'mode':'open', '_sid':sid},
                                stream=True)
```

Now it works. Bug is fixed.

Thank you so much!